Prove Asymptotic Stability of Origin
Take the system of equations given by $x' = y - x^3$, $y' = -y^3$. How can we prove asymptotic stability of the origin in this case?
I found an explanation given [here][1], but I am wondering if there is an easier way of showing it without these case analyses.
I feel like there should be an easier way.

If needed $y(t)$ can be computed explicitly, but what is important is only the fact that $y(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. Hence the first equation becomes an asymptotically autonomous equation
$$
\dot x=f(t)-x^3,
$$
which becomes $\dot x=-x^3$ in the limit $t\to\infty$. The only equilibrium here is $\hat x=0$ and hence the only omega limit set for the original system is also $\hat x=0$, which proves the asymptotic stability the attractivity of the origin (please see the comment below).

Thank you, this is a good explanation for why each trajectory goes to the origin as $t \to \infty$. I'm curious about how this would imply Lyapunov stability as well, since we need both Lyapunov stability and trajectories going to the origin. How do we know the trajectories $(x,y)$ won't leave an $\varepsilon$ size ball when starting there?

@QuantumINF0 Yes, you are correct, I was too quick to write my conclusion, my argument does not prove the stability, only the attractivity of the origin.

There is a Lyapunov function in the form of a fourth-order polynomial for this system. It is somewhat difficult to find it manually; fortunately, SOSTOOLS gives the following result:
$$
V(x,y)=0.2689x^4+1.206x^3y-8.145\cdot 10^{-11}x^3+200.8x^2y^2-2.574\cdot 10^{-9}x^2y+3.157\cdot 10^{-5}x^2+36.19xy^3+1.162\cdot 10^{-6}xy^2-1.129xy+4473.0y^4-0.0001551y^3+15880.0y^2
$$
